# dual-boot with secure boot: invalid signature

Tags: grub2, uefi, secure-boot

So, I got this Dell Inspiron 15 laptop with Windows 10 a couple of months ago.
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 to have as dual boot since I rarely use Windows.

Today, I did an update and some grub related packages were kept.
I don't know what I was thinking but I went on and `sudo install`ed the kept back packages.

After reboot, I get an invalid signature error and I get redirected to a Windows boot.

Is there a way to rectify the situation? My knowledge of EFI, secure boot and their interaction is fairly limited (going through info pages as I write this).

Comment: When you installed ubuntu - did you install it with secure boot enabled (UEFI setting) ?

Comment: i was oblivious that there was such a setting, so my guess is yes, since I haven't changed anything in BIOS so far.

Comment: i'm 99% sure, but how can I check in order to be completely positive?

Comment: Boot into BIOS (UEFI)  and check whether secure boot is turned on or off.

Comment: it is turned on; I've checked that. not enough rep to start a chat btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I do not know whether Microsoft did change the boot loader signature with the update
(this anyway would be off-topic here) I suggest the following procedure:

First **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot** in Windows.

Boot into Windows - open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Then disable (uncheck) Fast Boot in Control Panel -> Energy Settings (show hidden settings).

**Shutdown** the machine (do **NOT reboot**) completely.

Then reinstall GRUB bootloader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

Boot from the Ubuntu install media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Note :

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

If you do not know the partition numbers you can easily identify them with **GParted**.
The (Graphic User Interface) tool is already included in the Ubuntu installation media.

If this solution does not work you unfortunately will have to reinstall ubuntu in insecure mode.
Boot into BIOS (UEFI) and disable Secure Boot, then reinstall ubuntu in the way you did before.

Comment: what if I just disable "secure boot" as it is now? Also, if I follow your steps, and install with secure boot disabled, what will happen to windows?

Comment: When reinstalling GRUB in secure boot mode does not work, then disable secure boot and reinstall GRUB with secure boot disabled. Only when both ways don't work you need to reinstall ubuntu - and ... nothing will happen to Windows ... :)

Comment: my disk is sda, sda2 the efi partition and sda6 my system. I get an error "failed to get canonical path of /dev/sda2 on grub-install step. I also had to use --efi-directory because it is named EFI (which contains subdirs Boot, Microsoft,ubuntu)

Comment: I used them as such, with proper numbers per partition, that's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: is there a point in rebooting since I get the error described above while trying to reinstall grub? and yes they are the correct numbers.

Comment: rebooted anyway. same behaviour

Comment: Okay, then you'll have to reinstall ubuntu - do it exactly as advised in my answer (disable hibernation and fast boot in Windows / shutdown / disable secure boot / reinstall ubuntu) ! - Good luck ! Post back results please ...

Comment: I just need it to go to the exact same partition. do I need to watch out anything in particular during installation? also, with secure boot disabled? are you sure it won't affect windows 10 because I get a warning when I try to. Oh, and no fast boot option available.

Comment: Before installing ubuntu format the ubuntu partition (sda6) with ext4 using GParted. Choose 'Something else' when asked and install ubuntu to the same partition sda6 (mount point /) and GRUB to sda. Anyway to be on the safe side I always recommend to create a disk backup before. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, after several hours of catching up with the EFI documentation and even trying out rEFInd bootloader (which didn't work; I was getting the same message as for grub), I decided to disable 'secure boot' from the BIOS menu and it worked.

It seems that with my forced update I've overwritten the already cryptographically signed bootloader that Ubuntu was using since initial installation (I believe it is called shim).

Still though, I haven't understood how shim is used instead of grub.
(My guess is that it has to do with the configuration on the ESP; someone can correct me or answer this for me).

Comment: I don't know from where exactly you deduce that since you proposed a re-install and many of my questions were not answered. As I had written down, I just had no clue about EFI and the related concepts. In principle, I shouldn't give any points or accept your answer as it was misleading and didn't have the appropriate "stackexchange mentality" of explaining. It seems that you only care for rep/badges/etc, so I guess you can have it; I hate to disappoint.

Comment: First of all I am very glad that everything is working for you now ! Generally these "boot things" are a little bit complex and so solutions sometimes take their time. It is not easy always, especially when you think of different knowledge levels users have. As you can see in my profile I already helped many users to get their machines 'up and running' ... and please believe me, it's not for badges etc. - My approach is to help and I only get satisfaction from when problems were solved in the end. Thank you for collaboration and  accepting the answer and ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! Cheers :)